# AccessDeniedException - creating eks cluster - User is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster

Tags: amazon-eks

I am trying to run this command at the command line:

```
aws eks create-cluster \
    --name ignitecluster \
    --role-arn "$role_arn" \
    --resources-vpc-config  \ 
    subnetIds="$subnet_id",securityGroupIds="$security_group"
```

I get:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
> CreateCluster operation: User:
> arn:aws:iam::9136xxxx20371:user/ec2_resources is not authorized to
> perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource:
> arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:9136xxxx371:cluster/ignitecluster

I cannot for the life of me figure how to give this role permissions on `eks:*`, does anyone know?

Comment: nvm, it looks like this is a problem with my logged-in user, not with the role-arn

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To do this you will need to be a user or role that is allowed to edit IAM roles in the account.

In the AWS console, open the IAM service, click Users, select the user. On the Permissions tab click the Add Inline Policy link.

The following policy adds all permissions to the user.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "eksadministrator",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "eks:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The 'eksadministrator' value for Sid can be changed to something more appropriate for you.

Comment: This policy contains the following error: The following Statement Ids are invalid: eks-administrator, For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies.

I need to find another solution.

Comment: The Sid had an invalid character, I edited the response an removed that character, which was a dash. The old, invalid value was eks-administrator. You can also leave out the Sid, it is an optional identifier in the statement.

Comment: For me it also works by assigning the `AdminEKSPolicy` to the role.

Comment: @ThomasGotwigis that a custom policy?

Comment: Awesome, This code block fixed my issue. 
`"Action": "eks:*", "Resource": "*"`

Answer (score 2):

Go to IAM user, then to your specific user. Add a permissions policy to that user:

- Add inline policy.
- Go to visual editor and select EKS service.
- In action, select all EKS actions.
- For resources select all.
- For requested condition select none of them.

I will update this solution in future.

Comment: I updated your formatting, please review and edit or revert if I misunderstood the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can check your policies in IAM->access management->policies.
You can create a new policy or attach you account in one of exist policy.
Search "EKS" and add "CreateCluster" in the list, then create a new policy, problem solved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wP0G.png)

Comment: thanks i follow your instruction then i also make use of the cmd $ aws eks list-clusters 
To view the list of clusters that i have already created on aws eks console

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen due to `AWS Credentials` misconfigured. Just cross-check your r `.aws/crentials` with your `AWS iam credentials`.
If they are not the same, then go for `aws configure` and set the rest.
PS: Above answers are corrrect.But this situation hit for me