# travis-ci deployment to aws eks access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, travis-ci, amazon-eks, cicd

I am doing the same CI/CD pipeline but I cant figure out why my command kubectl apply -f k8s isnt working this is the reoccurring error

```
 "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:user/username is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:user/username Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254"
```

I'm thinking I set up my IAM policies wrong, this is what I thought would fix my problem but it did not, if anyone has experience with this I would appreciate your input

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:user/username"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think this is cause you do not have enough permission. Check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011492/accessdeniedexception-creating-eks-cluster-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform

Comment: Thank you sidharth vijayakumar that cleaned up my error,